# Using C program, executing "ctrl+r" on shell

Tags: c

Using C program, I want to execute "ctrl+r" on shell. How can I do this. I can use system() to run shell command from my program. But what would be the string sequence for system to execute 'ctrl+r' on shell.

thanks for reply. To further clarify, in my system, when buffer messages are flushed to console, I don't see the command I was typing on console. If I do 'ctrl+r' key manually on shell, then I see what I was typing. I want to run this 'ctrl+r' short cut from program itself. Is there a way to send 'ctrl+r' to shell to execute from program.

Comment: What do you mean by "execute "ctrl+r""? A keyboard-shortcut is not something you *execute*, it's something a program (such as the shell) recognizes and handles in its own way.

Comment: In a newly created shell? Is it useful? Anyway you may `fopen` in write mode `/dev/input/uinput` then send characters there. Or to use some external utility to feed one process with your inputs (you don't _execute_ `ctrl+r` as you don't execute `enter`).

Comment: thanks for reply. To further clarify, in my system, when buffer messages are flushed to console, I don't see the command I was typing on console. If I do 'ctrl+r' key manually on shell, then I see what I was typing. I want to run this 'ctrl+r' short cut from program itself. Is there a way to send 'ctrl+r' to shell to execute from program.